# Como atualizar os dados de outra tabela usando um trigger

Tags: mysql, trigger

Estou tentando cadastrar um produto em um carrinho, toda vez que ele for cadastrado la quer dizer q foi comprado, então sempre que isso acontecer quero diminuir a quantidade no estoque, tentei com a trigger abaixo, mas não deu certo:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER Tira BEFORE UPDATE
ON Carrinho
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.Carrinho.Produto = 198 THEN
        UPDATE Produto SET QuantidadeEstoque = (QauntidadeEstoque - 1);
    END IF;
    IF NEW.Carrinho.Produto = 135 THEN
        UPDATE Produto SET QuantidadeEstoque = (QauntidadeEstoque - 1);
    END IF;
    IF NEW.Carrinho.Produto = 244 THEN
        UPDATE Produto SET QuantidadeEstoque = (QauntidadeEstoque - 1);
    END IF;
    IF NEW.Carrinho.Produto = 562 THEN
        UPDATE Produto SET QuantidadeEstoque = (QauntidadeEstoque - 1);
    END IF;

END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Essa é a tabela:

[image: tabela produto essa com o estoque]

Comment: Notei um erro na palavra `QauntidadeEstoque`... não seria `QuantidadeEstoque`?

Comment: corrigi e nao mudou nada

Comment: isso ta certo??

Comment: nem eu, ja tentei de tudo e nao da certo, comecei a ver esses triggers hoje

Comment: Você quer que a mesma execute assim que um novo carrinho for cadastrado certo?

Comment: Nathan, pode postar a estrutura das tabelas que está utilizando? FIca mais fácil para enxergar o problema

Comment: posso sim, vou botar.

Comment: essa ai é a tabela produto